# How to suppress this warning in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, warnings, android-manifest

I have one line in my AndroidManifest.xml which produces a warning and that I can't fix :

`<activity android:name="com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity" />`

I have the following warning : `Use '$' instead of '.' for inner classes (or use only lowercase letters in package names)`

The problem is that if I replace the `.` for a `$`, the class won't work and I'll get an `ActivityNotFoundException`. I've read about **lints** in Android but I couldn't find the one I need.

Could you tell me how can I fix it ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to write `<activity android:name="com.paypal.android.mep.PayPalActivity" />`

Comment: is PayPalActivity an inner class of MEP class?

Comment: @LiaPronina Already tried it, ActivityNotFoundException raised.

Comment: @user2433059 Yes, I think so.

Comment: Did you try `<activity android:name="com.paypal.android.MEP$PayPalActivity" />` ? And it doesn't work? Then you have to make the Activity class a non inner class.

Comment: @user2433059 Yes already tried it too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lint rule is called `InnerclassSeparator`. It is in `Correctness` category.

[image]

Comment: Thanks you, I had forgot this menu ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can import the tools namespace:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Then ignore the warning on the specific element:

```
tools:ignore="InnerclassSeparator"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question: if "MEP" is the name of a package, then you can rename it to a lowercase name to solve the problem. Android Studio expects packages to start with a lowercase and Classes to start with an Uppercase.

1. Right click on your package folder in the project tree
2. Refactor > Rename
3. Change the name to lowercase and click Refactor
4. Clean your project build